# Trouble removing duplicates from list

Tags: javascript

```
//get email from test area

var emailList = document.getElementById("emailTextarea").value;
var emailListArray = emailList.split("\n");

//Remove yahoo and duplicates from the list

var usernamesArray = emailListArray.map(function(val, index, arr) {
    return val.slice(0, val.indexOf('yahoo.com'));
});
```

Comment: So what does "trouble" mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
emailListArray = ['123@gmail.com','123@yahoo.com','123@gmail.com','123@hotmail.com']
```

You can do something like this:

```
var usernamesArray = [];
emailListArray.forEach(function(item) {
     if(usernamesArray.indexOf(item) < 0 && item.indexOf('yahoo.com') < 0) {
         usernamesArray.push(item);
     }
});
```

First condition checks if the element in turn is not already in the array of results, second condition checks if the element doesn't contain the substring `yahoo.com`, if both are `true`, the element is added to the results.

After that, `usernamesArray` should have:

```
[ '123@gmail.com', '123@hotmail.com' ]
```

Comment: I copy your code but I cannot get it to work. There is nothing in the list. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's working for me, I added sample input and output. Does your code throws an error?